# Propositional truncation $||$-$||$ and double negation $\neg\neg$

Tags: type-theory, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic, homotopy-type-theory

I have a basic question about propositional truncation $||$-$||$ and double negation $\neg\neg$.

According to the recursion rule of $||$-$||$, $A\rightarrow B=||A||\rightarrow B$ as long as $B$ is a mere proposition (i.e., proof-irrelevant). Now let $B=\neg\neg A$, since $\neg\neg A$ is a mere proposition, and $A\rightarrow\neg\neg A$ is a tautology, we naturally conclude that

$$||A||\rightarrow\neg\neg A.\quad\quad(1)$$

Since $||A||\rightarrow\neg\neg A$ is a tautology, then $\neg\neg(||A||\rightarrow\neg\neg A)$ is also a tautology. Since $\neg\neg$ distributes over $\rightarrow$, we get the following

$$\neg\neg||A||\rightarrow\neg\neg A.\quad\quad(2)$$

Therefore, the following is also true:

$$\neg\neg(||A||\rightarrow A).\quad\quad(3)$$

But (3) looks quite crazy because it's almost the inverse of $A\rightarrow||A||$, though under $\neg\neg$. I don't know if these are all correct. I would appreciate if someone can tell if it's correct or if there is anything wrong with my derivations.

---

More: Since there is a mapping for $A\rightarrow||A||$, its double negation $\neg\neg(A\rightarrow||A||)$ is also a tautology. Together with (3), we have $\neg\neg(A\leftrightarrow||A||)$. Is there any place wrong with my derivation?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\neg\neg$ distributes over $\to$"?

Comment: @MikeShulman Thanks for the reply. It's $\neg\neg(\phi\rightarrow\psi)\leftrightarrow(\neg\neg\phi\rightarrow\neg\neg\psi)$.

Comment: That's not immediately obvious to me; why is it true?

Comment: @MikeShulman Hi Mike, you can take a look at Lemma 6.2.2 in van Dalen's textbook [Logic and Structure](http://93.174.95.29/main/976000/96fa5c52924e5dacbd190a6b18f0a69e/%28Universitext%29%20Dirk%20van%20Dalen%20-%20Logic%20and%20Structure-Springer%20%282013%29.pdf) (Click the link. It's an electronic version). The proof for this equivalence in intuitionistic logic is given on pages 159-160.

Comment: @MikeShulman, This is not the first time I see people ask this question, so I wrote up three proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753752/does-double-negation-distribute-over-implication-intuitionistically/).

Comment: @Z.A.K.Thanks for the proofs! Do you have any advice for my question in the post?

Comment: @EminiJask Not yet, but I am thinking about it. I don't have much intuition about whether $\neg\neg(||A|| \rightarrow A)$ is crazy or not: I'm predisposed to thinking that truncations are [weird](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2013/10/28/the-truncation-map-_-%E2%84%95-%E2%80%96%E2%84%95%E2%80%96-is-nearly-invertible/) anyway.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Thanks! I read that post before and also similar analyses in a paper by the same author Nicolai Kraus. I feel that it's crazy because it shows that $||A||\rightarrow A$ is always inhabited although the proof object is anonymous (due to $\neg\neg$)...

Comment: Regarding craziness, even having a function $\Vert A \Vert \to A$ for all $A$ would not be an *inverse* of $A\to \Vert A \Vert$, only a *section* of it.  That's essentially a strong axiom of choice, "every inhabited type has a specified element" -- strong enough to contradict univalence, but consistent to assume under UIP.  Note that the weaker statement that $\Vert (\Vert A \Vert \to A)\Vert$ holds for all $A$ is not contradictory, and indeed follows from LEM, but is still not constructively provable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you’ve said works, and there’s a simple intuition for it all:  $\neg\neg\cdot$ is a *modality*, and so is $\Vert\cdot\Vert$, and the latter is a “loosening” of the former.  Specifically, they’re equivalent under the former (that is, $\prod_{A : \mathcal{U}} \neg\neg (\Vert A\Vert \simeq \neg\neg A)$), because we can prove $\mathrm{LEM}_{\neg\neg} :\equiv \prod_{A : \mathcal{U}} \neg\neg (A + \neg A)$. So if we assume $\mathrm{LEM}_{-1} :\equiv \prod_{A : \mathcal{U}} \mathrm{isProp}(A) \to \left\Vert A + \neg A\right\Vert$, then the two modalities are purely equivalent too.

The way I like to think about this is that, in a classical setting, propositional truncation is just the same thing as double negation, which is [already well known to produce a classical environment in an otherwise constructive setting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation).  So in the general constructive-by-default setting of MLTT and its descendants, propositional truncation isn’t automatically equivalent to double negation, but you also can’t prove that it’s disequivalent without an explicit anticlassicality principle—and they’ll *always* be equivalent in the “forced classical” environment underneath double negation.

Answer (score 6):

Your arguments are correct as stated. It is indeed the case that the ($\Pi$-closures of the) types $\neg\neg (||A|| \rightarrow A)$ and $\neg\neg (||A|| \leftrightarrow A)$ are inhabited, and for the reasons outlined above.

The second part of your question far subtler: it asks about the "craziness" of the fact that these types are inhabited. I'm not sure how to answer this (although I suspect that a good answer is possible, and will eventually be penned by someone else). In the meantime, I offer a few remarks.

It's not surprising that we have functions $|| \bot || \rightarrow \bot$ or $||\mathbb{N}|| \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ for fixed types $\bot, \mathbb{N}$. However, we certainly would not expect any term to inhabit $\Pi A:\mathbf{U}.||A|| \rightarrow A$. However, actually *proving* that there is no term of that type seems like a task that would involve fairly elaborate semantic reasoning (assuming that this is indeed the case; I might ask a followup question about this later).

The fact that we can construct an inhabitant of the type $\Pi A:\mathbf{U}.\neg\neg (||A|| \rightarrow A)$ is a pleasant surprise, but it does not say much about the inhabitedness of the former, as we still can't prove $\neg\neg \Pi A:\mathbf{U}.(||A|| \rightarrow A)$. In fact, there is a fairly direct proof of $\Pi A:\mathbf{U}.\neg\neg(||A|| \rightarrow A)$ that does not invoke the distributivity of $\neg\neg$, and might illuminate what's going on.

We can prove $\Pi A:\mathbf{U}.\neg(||A|| \rightarrow A) \rightarrow \neg A$ simply by taking $f : \neg(||A|| \rightarrow A)$ and $a : A$, and constructing $f(\lambda x.a) : \bot$. Similarly, we can prove $\Pi A:\mathbf{U}. \neg A \rightarrow ||A|| \rightarrow A$ since given $a : || A ||$ and $f: A \rightarrow \bot$ we can get $\mathrm{squashrec}(f): || A || \rightarrow \bot$, and then $\mathrm{squashrec}(f)(a) : \bot$. Putting these together we have a term of type $\Pi A:\mathbf{U}.\neg(||A|| \rightarrow A) \rightarrow || A || \rightarrow A$, from which $\Pi A:\mathbf{U}.\neg\neg(||A|| \rightarrow A)$ readily follows.

Comment: "I suspect that a good answer is possible, and will eventually be penned by someone else"  --  indeed, it looks like one might have appeared while I was writing this answer.

Comment: One can prove internally that $\Pi A:\mathbf{U}. \Vert A\Vert\to A$ contradicts the univalence axiom; this is Exercise 3.11 in the [HoTT Book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/).  Thus, since the univalence axiom is consistent (which might be considered "elaborate semantic reasoning"), that type is uninhabitable.